# Is axios delaying http requests

Tags: node.js, http, https, axios, xmlhttprequest

We are building an interface for a client in which we are doing a high volume of data synchronization, as we are moving forward by activation of multiple levels of interface, we found a unique issue.

The unique issue is when we basically sync the data from one system to another, we are using HTTPS Axios module to do so and while processing the data we found a huge amount of occasional latency coming in from our destination system, by comparing the logs we found that, the HTTP request created at our end reached the destination system with a few minutes delay.Our understanding is that it might be Axios who is adding delay as we found [this Git issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2609)

`Infra setup:` We have a k8 cluster setup. Our interface is built on NodeJs.
Nodejs v15.3.0
Axios v0.19.2

Please guide me on this as it's a bit critical topic.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the issue I brought up with the axios repo. It's hard to say if the same thing is causing the problem that you've described, but certainly plausible. You could try forking axios off of my pull request branch and running your code off of that:
https://github.com/axios/axios/pull/2702

The branch is off of v0.19.2 axios so you shouldn't run into any compatibility issues.

Comment: Should be. You can also do a fork with its own version.

Comment: Thanks @Sasha for helping immediately on this topic. We found it was NAT gateway issue and also we replaced the http client package to GOT.