# Axios latency issue

Tags: node.js, https, axios, latency

We are doing a high volume of data synchronization from database1 to database2 using triggers on database1. We found occasional latency coming from our server1(firebase function). We are making AXIOS https post request on firebase function to server2, upon document change. If a document get's two changes at almost same time, requests are not reaching the server2 in the same order, they got triggered on the firebase function.

I figured out this issue via logging before making request on firebase function and logging right after reaching the server2.

Is there any possibility that the latency issue is with axios and will using default https module instead of axios, solve my problem ?

- axios: 0.27.2
- nodejs: 16

There's an old thread on the same, but it didn't helped me well.

[Is axios delaying http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283818/is-axios-delaying-http-requests)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.